# How to Write Eloquent query for retrieving data from Partitioned Table

Tags: eloquent, partitioning

I am working on database partitioning and using laravel framework for development.
I am trying to convert raw query to Eloquent.

Ex. My query is like SELECT * FROM employee PARTITION (p2)
so using raw queries its like

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM employee PARTITION (p2)") );

I am not able to convert it if I use Eloquent as in Eloquent query syntax is like ClassName::select('*')->where()->get();
and my query does not contain where clause.

What is the way to convert this query?
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like this:

```
$results = YourModel::partition('anno2024')
->where('cliente_id', '=', 120)
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();
```